# having problems returning value from functions

Tags: javascript, function, oop, events

Hello Im having problems returning a value from the `AmountToDisplay()` function I feel like a module approach  would be appropriate but since I'm new to OOP I've been having problems setting that up

```
function AmountToDisplay(){
    $emitter = $({});
    $('#amountItems').change(function(){
        var amountchosen = $("#amountItems option:selected").val();
        $emitter.trigger('amountUpdate', amountchosen);
    });

    $emitter.on('amountUpdate', function(e, val){
        if(val == 2){
            return 2;
        }else if(val == 3){
            return 3;
        }else if(val == 4){
            return 4;
        }
    })
}
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
if(AmountToDisplay() ==2){
    ..append 2 items to body
}else if(AmountToDisplay() ==3){
    ..append 3 items to body
}
```

`console.log(AmountToDisplay())` gives undefined

instead of returning and I use the alert method `alert(2)`, it works. I'm trying to get the values out of the select box so I could decouple separate the value  from the event so I could use the value in other part of my code [other parts in my code in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdf083Lb/1/). Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT** THE thing is I want to be able to use the amount somewhere out of the change event. so if the user clicked 3  I want to be able to have that value so I could perform another function not related to the change event even though the value changes when the user inputs.  pub/sub?

Comment: You can't use the return statement for asynchronous results. Read up more on javascript asynchronous execution. (One tool you might be interested in is called a promise)

Comment: (Also consider what your current return statement does: it's not the amountToDisplay function returning, but the anonymous event handler of the 'amountUpdate' event)

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I was wondering if this can be done in a module pattern way. for example to make a private variable 'amountreturned' and make a method that changes the variable and that variable is returned (public) so I could use `if(amountToDisplay.amountreturned == 2) {show 2}` because I don't think that's possible. I think all the answers are going to connect the change event and it will be tightly coupled. I want to get better OOP. bu this was helpful.

Comment: You can use a module pattern, but the control flow can't be synchronous in this case. If you resolve a promise from within that anonymous event handler, the function can maintain a reference to "private" data in a so-called [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going through the backdoor. use arguments to cheat in the variable you want.

```
$emitter.on('amountUpdate', function(e, val){
            console.log(arguments);
            if(val == 2){
                return 2;
            }else if(val == 3){
                return 3;
            }else if(val == 4){
                return 4;
            }
        })
```

you can see the variable you want is in arguments[1]
Also returning anything here doesn't serve a function. it does literally nothing.

You would need to pass it to an event handler.

so by modifying your code like this:

```
 $emitter.on('amountUpdate', function(e, val){
        val = arguments[1];
        if(val == 2){
            myEventHandlerfor2(val,e);
        }else if(val == 3){
            myEventHandlerfor3(val,e);
        }else if(val == 4){
            myEventHandlerfor4(val,e);
        }
    })
```

**edit for showing how to put it in an object**

```
function FruitBasket() {
    this.apples = 0;
    this.pears = 0;
    this.bananas = 0;
    this.iwonteatthat = 0;
}
FruitBasket.prototype.addFruit = function(which) {
    switch(which) {
        case 0 : this.apples++;break;
        case 1 : this.pears++;break;
        case 2 : this.bananas++;break;
        case 0 : this.iwonteathat++;break;
    }
}
FruitBasket.prototype.registerManipulator = function(manipulator) {
    if(!(manipulator instanceof jQuery)) {
        manipulator = $(manipulator);
    }
    manipulator.on('amountUpdate', jQuery.proxy(function(e, val){
        val = arguments[1];
        this.addFruit(val);
    },this);

}

myFruitBasket = new FruitBasket();
myFruitBasket.registerManipulator($('#formfieldstuff'));
myFruitBasket.registerManipulator(document.getElementById('OtherManipulator'));
```

Comment: I like this one, but isn't there a way to make this less coupled. I see I can't have the value returned I was going for a pub/sub type of pattern. I was wondering if this can be done in a module pattern way. for example to make a private variable 'amountreturned' and make a method that changes the variable and that variable is returned (public) so I could use if(amountToDisplay.amountreturned == 2) {show 2} because I don't think that's possible. Your answer was helpful it's the best one so far

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way around. The event is the thing that pushes. but if you want to put it in an object for future manipulation you can always use jquery proxy to set it to do stuff with an object. i'll update the example with a thingy.

Answer (score 0):

The return that do you have only exits the function of the event, but not the function AmountToDisplay.

1. The event must be outside the function
2. The function only need to return the value of the select with amountItems
3. The console.log or your logic must be inside the event

http://jsfiddle.net/mdf083Lb/2/

```
function AmountToDisplay(){
    return $("#amountItems option:selected").val();
}
$("select").change(function(){
    console.log(AmountToDisplay());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to defina an event method or something else, you can get selected value of select box where ever you want by using jquery selector :

```
var amountToDisplay = $("#amountItems option:selected").val();
```

Comment: amountTodDisplay won't change when the user selects a different amount. That's  why I need a change method.